# How to put an SVG in a DIV on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have this code and it works fine.

```
var play = function(){
    $( this ).click(function() {
        console.log( "Test" );
    });
}
```

I want to replace console.log( "Test" ); with an SVG that renders in the clicked div and not sure how to do that. I also want to SVGs to alternate per click so I wrote this:

```
var changePlayer = function(){
    if (){
        // X Player
    } else
        // O Player
};
```

Do I have to pass changePlayer into Play?

Comment: You can work with SVG just like with HTML DOM structure - dynamically add it, remove it from DOM, edit it's attributes and properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
var play = function(){
    $( this ).click(function(e) {
        var targetBox = (e.target.id);
        $("#" + targetBox).append("<svg></svg>");

    });
}
```

This worked..